# How do I write this in a way that python does not interpret the data as unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

**CODE:**

```
class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello World!")
```

**Error:**

##raise TypeError("Data must not be unicode")
builtins.TypeError: Data must not be unicode  ##

How do i write the code to be utf-8?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Python3, try:

```
"Hello World!".encode('utf-8')
```

If your data is in a `str` variable, try:

```
# s = "Hello World!"
s.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's seems like you're building a server, try using `b'Hello World'` to convert to bytes.

Comment: This gets rid of the error log! Thank you! but the program prints out "b'\x00&C:\\Users\\J\\.PyCharm2017.1\\config\x00&C:\\Users\\J\\.PyCharm2017.1\\system\x00\x03---' instead of "Hello World!" any ideas on how to improve this? Thank you!

Comment: @JessicaWarren What does it print out?

Comment: b'\x00&C:\\Users\\J\\.PyCharm2017.1\\config\x00&C:\\Users\\J\\.PyCharm2017.1\\system\x00\x03---'

Comment: @JessicaWarren Using `x.decode()` to convert `x` which is bytes back to string.

Comment: do you mean self.transport.write("Hello World!").decode()? this spits errors about attributes

Comment: @JessicaWarren No, I'm assuming `transport.write(b'Hello World!')` is sending the message to a server, then upon receival (on the server side) you want to convert the it back to string by `.decode()`.